# What does "Be-ness" and "Is-ness" mean

Tags: terminology, suffixes

In a book about spirituality the author uses the words "I-ness", "is-ness" and "be-ness". These words aren't in my dictionary.  How can I understand words like "be-ness", can I add "-ness" to the end of any word?

> The speaker's or the listener's ego ("I know this" and " I don't know this") always takes him to I-ness instead of **Be-ness** and **Is-ness.** [no source]

Comment: The phrases "be-ness" and "is-ness" have no meaning in standard English.  You have to read the context to understand how the author has defined them, or at least suggests some distinction between the two.  Otherwise I can only make an educated guess, probably no better than you can do yourself.

Comment: The question "What is this in Spanish" is off topic (it is a question of Spanish, not English) If you can cite your source there is an on-topic question about the meaning of "is-ness".

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the **-ness** endings are hyphenated in this sentence indicates that the writer has made up these words by adding **-ness** to an existing word.

Generally we add the suffix **ness** to convert an adjective that describes a quality to a noun that describes the corresponding quality, when there isn't already an appropriate noun available.  For example, **good** (adj) + **ness** give **goodness** (noun).

If the writer had added **-ness** to an adjective, we would know exactly what the made up word was supposed to mean. In this case, the writer has added them to pronouns and verbs, so the standard interpretation would not apply.

My guess is that, given that this is about spirituality, it is a rather crude attempt to talk about a move away from thinking of things in terms of how it relates to oneself (I-ness) to thinking about things as having an existence in their own right (be-ness, is-ness).